# can 'knife diff' be told to ignore binary files?

Tags: chef

I maintain many chef cookbooks that are worked on by various teams. Some teams choose to include binary files in the cookbooks.

Before uploading a modified cookbook i like to 'knife diff' to double check the changes... but if there is a binary file in there which has changed then the screen explodes with the binary file changed content.

Does anyone know how to exclude binary files from the knife diff command or another workaround ?

thank you 
fLo

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to avoid binary files is to leverage the --diff-filter option to filter for non binary files

DOC: http://docs.opscode.com/knife_diff.html